# Left UIBarButton Item has extra padding to its right

Tags: ios7, uibarbuttonitem

I have a custom UIBarButtonItem that uses an image. There seems to be a lot of extra padding around the button (10 px + I believe). I've seen solutions of how to remove the padding to the left, but my issue is that there is padding to the right.

My buttons image is only 44x44 but I believe the tappable space in iOS7 is more like 44-50 x ~80.

How can remove this space? I can't set a negative space (e.g - 10) to the right of my image because I believe that will be added after my buttons padding.

Comment: have you looked into just adjusting the z-index relative to other UI elements nearby? Not sure if that would fix your problem

Comment: @Dan I havent looked at the z-index, thanks ill check it out.